# Hexadecimal data processing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, type-conversion, decimal, hex

I have a string of Hex data streaming out as my data, it looks like this:
"00 E1 08 A2 05 FF"

I need them concatenated and then converted to decimal in column format, something like this:

00E1

08A2

05FF

Finally after conversion to decimal:

225

2210

1535

Total data available is 70,000.

Anyone can help me? I'm a newbie in Matlab, I tried writing the following code but no luck.

```
N=140000; %N is the number of data
n=N/2; %n is the number of concatenated data
filename=input('\nFile-name: ','s');
data_import=importdata(filename,' ', 1);

data_char=char(data_import);
data_str=sscanf(data_char, '%s', [N,1]);
data_out=textscan(data_str, '%4c',n);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`importdata` based approach -

```
data_import = importdata(filename,'')
C = regexp(data_import,' ','Split')
C1 = C{:}
t1 = reshape(C1(~cellfun(@isempty,C1)),2,[]).' %//'
data_out = hex2dec([char(t1(:,1)) char(t1(:,2))])
```

---

Alternative `textscan` based approach -

```
fileID = fopen(filename);
data_import = textscan(fileID,'%s')
fclose(fileID);

t1 = reshape(data_import{:}.',2,[]).'
data_out = hex2dec([char(t1(:,1)) char(t1(:,2))])
```

Comment: I tried the importdata based approach but I get this error when runnin it: Error using reshape
Product of known dimensions, 2, not divisible into total
number of elements, 144001.

Error in hex2dec_processing_b (line 4)
t1 = reshape(C{:},2,[]).' %//'

Comment: @Chris Try the edited `importdata` based approach. I think `textscan` based approach must have worked too, did you try that one too?

Comment: Hey Divakar, the importdata version now works flawlessly!! =D Thank you very much for your help, been trying to solve this for 1hr++ with no luck >_<

Answer (score 0):

```
filename=input('\nFile-name: ','s');
data_import=importdata(filename,' ', 1);
data_char=char(data_import);
data_str=sscanf(data_char, '%s', [N,1]);
data_out = [];
for i=1:4:N
   a = data_str(i:i+4);
   d = hex2dec(a);
   data_out = [data_out;d];
end
```

Hope this helps..

Edit:

Example String: 00 D5 00 CE 00 C7 00 C0 00 B9 00 D5 00 CE 00 C7 00 C0 00 B9 00 D5 00 CE 00 C7 00 C0 00 B9

Code:

```
data = '00 D5 00 CE 00 C7 00 C0 00 B9 00 D5 00 CE 00 C7 00 C0 00 B9 00 D5 00 CE 00 C7 00 C0 00 B9';
a = regexprep(num2str(data,17), '\s', '');
sizeOfA = size(a,2);
data_out = [];
for i = 1:4:sizeOfA
    a1 = a(i:i+3);
    d = hex2dec(a1);
    data_out = [data_out;d];
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried using a stream of 30 hex but it seems that the resulted decimal is not what is expected.

I use this as input: 00 D5 00 CE 00 C7... (total of 30) the resulted decimal is 3408, 3296, etc which is not what I expected. The expected result is 213 (00D5), 206(00CE), 199(00C7)...

I'm not sure what's wrong though. The amount of decimal available is also half what is expected (30 string I expected 15 dec).

Comment: 00 D5 00 CE 00 C7 00 C0 00 B9 00 D5 00 CE 00 C7 00 C0 00 B9 00 D5 00 CE 00 C7 00 C0 00 B9